# Vstest.console in powershell and Action Based on results

Tags: powershell, vstest.console.exe

I'm trying to run some functional unit tests using vstest.console in PowerShell, and if any tests fails, I would perform a certain action (in this case, it would be rolling back an installation). How do I go about doing that.

Here is the current content of the PowerShell script I have.

```
$command = "<path_to_vstest_directory>\vstest.console.exe"
$arguments = @('<test dll>', '/Tests:"<name_of_specific_test_to_run>"')
&$command $arguments
```

Comment: Automatic variable `$LASTEXITCODE` contains the exit code of the most recently executed external program; `exit $LASTEXITCODE` allows you to use that exit code as your script's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Start-Process` cmdlet to gain some control over the executed process:

```
$command = "<path_to_vstest_directory>\vstest.console.exe"
$testDll = "Path\with space\test.dll"
$testName = "name_of_specific_test_to_run"
$process = Start-Process $command -ArgumentList "`"$testDll`" /Tests:`"$testName`"" -PassThru -Wait
```

After that, you can evaluate the exit code stored in `$process.ExitCode`. You have also the possibility to redirect `stdout` and `stderr`, if needed.